# Android separate packages

Tags: android, android-activity, package

I have a large UI (about 20-25 screens).  How should I organize my code?  Should I separate by functionality into different packages? Should I have one package for all UI classes and then create sub packages to organize?  Or should I not create separate packages and organize into folders.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a folder, it becomes a package. My favourite structure for large projects is as follows:

- UI
- Core / Logic
- DAO / Connections
- Utils
- Models / TOs / VOs

Hope this helps.

Comment: Every Activity needs a separate class. If you mean about putting classes in different packages, this is nearly imperceptible. You should not worry about this at all. Java has over 15 years improving this particular algorithms so they are not noticeable even to developers. It's benefits are absolutely greater than this.

Comment: good call. a similar strategy is used by the Google I/O app, which is supposed to demonstrate best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to separate my classes in logical packages as much as possible.

- activities
- adapters (adapters for listviews mostly)
- asynctasks (communication with the server for the most part)
- core (contains a constants class and the base activity that holds the global vairables, as well as the sliding menu and action bar)
- fragments
- interfaces (mostly listener/observer pattern interfaces, used to notify for success/failure of an asynctask or database operation)
- localsqlitedb (contains the sqlqueries class, the database helper class and other db-related classes)
- objects - contains plain old java objects (pojos) representing different entities from my app (a user, a user's item, a category)
- utilities - images handling, email senders, custom toast makers and so on

I think its easy to maintain and reuse code organized this way

I also use naming conventions so I know what a class or a file is about at a glance

in the layouts folder:

```
activity_login.xml
activity_register.xml
dialog_delete_profile_confirmation.xml
```

in the drawable folder:

```
icon_feed.xml
icon_search.xml
images_loading_splash_screen.png
images_default_avatar.png
```

in the asynctasks package

```
GetUserDataFromServerAsync.class
RegisterUserAsync.class
```

(so that when I refer these in the code I know its not the internal handler class, but the class that communicates with the server)